# Guiding tensorflow keras model training to achieve best Recall At Precision 0.95 for binary classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, precision-recall

I am hoping to get some help on the titular topic.
I have a database of medical data of patients with two similar pathologies, one severe and one much less so. I need flag most of the formers (≥95%) and leave out as many of the latter as possible.

Therefore, I want to create a binary classifier that reflects this. Looking around on the web (not an expert) I put together this piece of code, substituting the metric I found with RecallAtPrecision(0.95) in the middle part of the code. Below is an abridged version:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, input_dim=x_train.shape[1], activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RecallAtPrecision(0.95)])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=0.33, batch_size=16, epochs=EPOCHS)
```

However, it simply doesn't work, as it throws the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.keras.metrics' has no attribute 'RecallAtPrecision'

I am at a loss about why that happened, as I can clearly see it in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/RecallAtPrecision). The code works if I use Recall(), Precision() or most any other metrics. Looking around some more, I am beginning to think I am missing something fundamental.
Do any of you fine ladies and gentlemen have any pointers on how to solve this problem?

Comment: which version of tensorflow do you have? you linked to the documentation of tf2.8

Comment: Oooh. Yes, that. That was the problem. I relied on the package manager to keep things up to date but it did not work. A simple manual install later and it works. Now, as I suspected, this is not enough to do what I wanted to do but at least I can continue working on it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

To calculate precision and recall, you don't need require Keras. If you have your actual and expected values as vectors of 0/1, you can calculate TP, FP, FN using `tf.count_nonzero`, you can easily represent them.

```
TP = tf.count_nonzero(predicted * actual)
FP = tf.count_nonzero(predicted * (actual - 1))
FN = tf.count_nonzero((predicted - 1) * actual)
```

Your metrics are now simple to calculate:

```
precision = TP / (TP + FP)
recall = TP / (TP + FN)
```

Comment: This is not what the question is asking...

Comment: Indeed, that is not what I was looking for, unfortunately.